# how to make alpha part of movieClip non-clickable (actionscript starling)?

Tags: actionscript, air, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I am using Starling.
I can't figure out how to make alpha part of bitmap non-clickable - say I have a rabbit in center and alpha around.

first i embed the bitmap:

```
[Embed(source="assets/stuff.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]public static const Axml:Class;
[Embed(source="assets/stuff.png")]public static const Apng:Class;
```

Then create the bitmap atlass (spritesheet):

```
var tx1:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(new Apng());
var xm1:XML = XML(new Axml());
var atlas:TextureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(tx1, xm1);
```

I made a MovieClip and add bitmap to it like that:

```
var movie:MovieClip = new MovieClip(atlas.getTextures("rabbit_run_"), 18);
addChild(movie);
movie.play();


starling.core.Starling.juggler.add(movie);
```

but when I click on it even on alpha part movieClip becomes "clicked". 
I only need **rabbit itself** to be clickable, not around it!

How to make alpha non-clickable? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1: You cannot make image clickable in one area and nonclickable in another. But you can get color of pixel under mouse and ignore ckicks over transparent pixels

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var rabbitBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rabbit.width, rabbit.height, true, 0xFFFFFFFF);
rabbitBitmap.draw(rabbit);

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mmh)
rabbit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mch)
rabbit.buttonMode = true;

function mmh(e:MouseEvent):void {
  rabbit.useHandCursor = getAlpha() != 255;
}

function mch(e:MouseEvent):void {
  if (getAlpha() != 255) {
    // ... do someth
  }
}

function getAlpha ():int {
  var rgba:uint = rabbitBitmap.getPixel32(rabbit.mouseX, rabbit.mouseY);
  return rgba & 0xff;
}
```

2: Use vector graphics for your rabbit :)